# Not able to create new TinkerGraph in Tinkerpop3

Tags: groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am trying to create a new tinker graph. But it is giving following exception

i am very new to graph databases. I just have installed tinkerpop3 on ubuntu linux. can some one help me if i am missing any thing, Thanks.

```
 gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()

 No such property: TinkerGraphFactory for class: groovysh_evaluate
    Display stack trace? [yN] y
    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TinkerGraphFactory for class: groovysh_evaluate
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:68)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:159)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:121)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:93)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:99)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:636)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:230)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the right syntax for TinkerPop3.  To create the "classic" graph from TinkerPop2 you have to do:

```
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createClassic()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V()
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
==>v[5]
==>v[6]
```

Comment: Thank u for your reply.But it is not working.please let me inform if any additional work to be done. can u please tell me if there any material is available for practice of tinkerpop3.

Comment: I can't say what you are doing wrong.  Note my updated answer from an actual Gremlin Console session.  There is tons of documentation here: http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph   i am not getting the above lines.is there any xml configuration i dont know

Comment: These things should just work out of the box.  Are you using the pre-built distribution? http://tinkerpop.com/downloads/3.0.0.M5/gremlin-console-3.0.0.M5.zip

Comment: Thank u. it is working fine after activating server, utilities, tinkergraph. my doubt is how can we communicate with java program to tinker graph database. can u please help me.

Comment: thank u it is working. my doubt is how can we communicate with java program to tinkerpop graph database

Comment: TinkerGraph is an in-memory java database.  You are communicating with it by virtue of opening it.  Perhaps you should read through the documentation a bit more and then post some more specific questions about your doubts as needed.

Comment: I have the same problem:
g = TinkerFactory.createClassic()
gives:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TinkerFactory for class: groovysh_evaluate
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:51)

Comment: The above commands are for TinkerPop3.  I can only assume that you are using a TinkerPop2 distribution.   There should be no problem with this command using the distribution defined in the comments above (copied here to avoid any confusion: http://tinkerpop.com/downloads/3.0.0.M5/gremlin-console-3.0.0.M5.zip)

Answer (score 0):

For 3.3, you need to use `g = TinkerFactory.createModern()`

For more details, refer [Apache TinkerPop Getting Started](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/tutorials/getting-started/)

Hope this helps